# How to merge two rows with the same value in a given column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hey I have a DataFrame like this:

```
d =  {"KEY": ["KEY2", "KEY2"], "String value": ["value 1", "value 2"], "list value": [["val1"], ["val2"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

In `KEY` column there is the same value in both rows. What I want to do is to create one row from this two rows (or more in my DataFrame) in such a way that values from from a given columns (except `KEY` and possibly one more column) are added. So finally I want sth like this:

```
d2 = {"KEY": ["KEY2"], "String value": ["value 1" + "value 2"], "list value": [["val1"] + ["val2"]]}
res = pd.DataFrame(d2)
res
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` and `sum`

it is possible to process columns separately and leave some columns "unchanged" by keeping the first value, assuming it is the same for rows with the same key.

```
d =  {"KEY": ["KEY2", "KEY2"], "String value": ["value 1", "value 2"], "list value": [["val1"], ["val2"]],
      "other value": [1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('KEY')['String value'].apply(lambda x:'\n'.join(x)))
df2['list value'] = df.groupby('KEY')['list value'].sum()
df2['other value'] = df.groupby('KEY')['other value'].first()
df2
```

```
    KEY     String value    list value
0   KEY2    value 1value 2  [val1, val2]
```

Comment: thank you :) How can I add newline `\n` between added `String value`? Is it possible? What is more, what if I have one more column, say `Type` for which I don't want to perform summation?

Comment: @Mr.Hedge you cannot leave out one column unchanged because the new DataFrame would be of different shape compared to the old one

Comment: @Mr.Hedge see the updated answer assuming you mean unchanged by they all have the same value